# OWIN ApiController access to the request body/stringified JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, owin

This is in OWIN & .Net 4.5.2

Using debug I'm proving this controller's method is being called by the web request.

My thing is the request body contains a JSON stringified object:

> "{ 'id':'12', 'text1':'hello', 'test2':'world' }"

Which is applicably encoded as it is transferred on the line.

I've tried so many things I'm so confused now.

**How do I get the decoded string so I can JSON.Parse() that or better yet get .Net to just given me an object?**

In one version (long ago now) I had a defined type for this object.  If I need that great, not a high challenge.  But if I only have the JSON object from the string that's fine too.

```
public class cController : ApiController {

    [HttpPut]
    public string put(string id) {
        var bdy = this.Request.Content;

        //Console.WriteLine("PUT containers {0}", body);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In case it helps, the `bdy.ContentReadStream` is null.  I don't know if this is good, bad, or important.  Maybe `Request.Content` isn't the way to go but seems to me like if I'm going to read the body as a stream then it shouldn't be null.

I also tried working through `System.Web.HttpContext`.  If that is somehow the answer I have no problem going back to that.  But I couldn't find the secret sauce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the desired model as a parameter to the action and the frame work should be able to parse it provided it is valid JSON

```
public class cController : ApiController {

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(string id,[FromBody] Model body) {
        if(ModelState.IsValue) {    
            return Ok(body.text1);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Where `Model` is defined as

```
public class Model {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: D@MN! You the man.  I even went down this road before.  But I didn't understand the [FromBody] decoration.  In fact, I'd never seen a decoration of a variable at it's declaration as a passed in parameter.  Makes total sense to me now and I'm SO happy to use it; even if I can't thank of any reason I'd _create_ this for myself.  Thank you, thank you.